# scroll bar doesn't appear on JList

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, jscrollbar

I'm using a `GridBagLayout` and have a `JList` of my custom class. The `JList` itself is shown as I expect, but the scroll bar doesn't appear. (My size of data is also larger than the size of my `JList`.) I checked many of related links and all of them mentioned these 2 lines to do so, but it didn't work for me.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list); 

add(scrollPane);
```

Full code:

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UserPart extends JFrame {
    Label messageL = new Label("Confirm an item for more options.");
    Button confirmB = new Button("Confirm");
    Button backB = new Button("Back");
    DefaultListModel<User2> model;
    public UserPart() {

        JList<User2> list = new JList<User2>();
        model = new DefaultListModel<User2>();
        for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity2.arr.size(); i++) {
            User2 u = new User2();
            u.setForShow(i);
            model.addElement(u);
        }
        // SETTING THE APPEARANCE OF THE JLIST
        list.setModel(model);
        list.setCellRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer());
        list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 750));
        //////////////////////////////////////////////    
        GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        setLayout(grid);
        setTitle("List of users");
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        this.setLayout(layout);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        this.add(messageL, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        this.add(list, gbc); //ADDED JLIST TO LAYOUT HERE
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list); // DEFINED SCROLL BAR HERE
        add(scrollPane); // ADDED SCROLL BAR TO LAYOUT HERE
        setSize(1000, 1500);
        setPreferredSize(getSize());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add the list separately. You have to enclose it with the JScrollPane and then add the scrollPane. Try `this.add(new JScrollPane(list), gbc);` instead of `this.add(list, gbc);`

Comment: If you did want to add `scrollPane` to the container, it ought to have constraints as well. Also it's better to ask questions with a *Meal Ready to Eat* https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Still doesn't work. @tgallei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the constraints weight (`weightx`, `weighty`) to a value greater than zero - to use all the layout - also set `fill` to `BOTH`. Do not add the list directly to the frame, just add the scroll pane **with** the constraints set as explained above. Do not mix AWT components (`Label`) with Swing ones, use `JLabel` instead. Here the summary:

```java
JLabel label = new JLabel("Confirm an item for more options.");

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
frame.add(label, gbc);
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
frame.add(scroll, gbc);
```